# Passport-local missing credentials

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport-local

I keep getting this error after trying everything I know and what I saw online. It's tiring.
Can't even find a solution from other posts for this problem.

Code:

```
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

// Load User Model
const User = require("../models/User");

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, (email, password, done) => {
      // Match User
      User.findOne({ email: email })
        .then((user) => {
          if (!user) {
            return done(null, false, {
              message: "That email is not registered",
            });
          }

          // Match Password
          bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (isMatch) {
              return done(null, user);
            } else {
              return done(null, false, { message: "Password incorrect" });
            }
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
};
```

```
// Handling login Logic
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/campgrounds",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true,
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Form:

```
<% include ./partials/header %>

<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <h1 class="text-center mb-3"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Login</h1>
      <% include ./partials/messages %>
      <form action="/login" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Password"
          />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
      </form>
      <p class="lead mt-4">No Account? <a href="/register">Register</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

setup:

```
const express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
  mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  flash = require("connect-flash"),
  Campground = require("./models/campground"),
  Comment = require("./models/comment"),
  passport = require("passport"),
  methodOverride = require("method-override");
// (User = require("./models/user")), (seedDB = require("./seeds"));

// Passport config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// Requiring Routes
const commentRoutes = require("./routes/comments"),
  campgroundRoutes = require("./routes/campgrounds"),
  indexRoutes = require("./routes/index");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(flash());
mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);

// DB config
const db = require("./config/keys").database;

// Connect to Mongo
mongoose
  .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected..."))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

// seedDB(); // seed the database

// Passport config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// PASSPORT CONFIGURATION
app.use(
  require("express-session")({
    secret: "Dani is great",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash("success_msg");
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash("error_msg");
  res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
  next();
});

app.use("/", indexRoutes);
app.use("/campgrounds", campgroundRoutes);
app.use("/campgrounds/:id/comments", commentRoutes);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("The DanCamp server has started");
});
```

I've tried everything possible, but I'm still getting this error.
I think there's something missing here, cause I tried this codes in another project and it works perfectly.

I'm in desperate need of help here please.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code that makes the request to the POST /login endpoint, as well as what middleware you set up to parse the incoming request body?

Comment: for the request to the post/login code is above and I didn't use a middleware for it.

Comment: The code above is the route handler for the POST /login endpoint. How do you actually send the request to this endpoint? Do you submit a form, use a http client library... Show how the request to this endpoint is actually put together in the first place. Also, you need to set up a body parser in your middleware pipeline for `req.body` to be populated.

Comment: I've added it. @IAmDranged

Comment: For what it's worth, I just ran your code successfully - just basically commented out mongoose and routes related stuff to make it work with my setup.

Comment: Okay, so what do I need to do for it to run successfully on mine?